# MySQL Connector/J ReplicationDriver: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, amazon-web-services, mysql-connector

I am using MySQL Connector/J ReplicationDriver for the master/slave connection load balancing in AWS where I am having one master & two read-only slaves running.
The problem I am facing is if suppose there is no write request is sent to the mysql database from an app server for some long time like 2-3 hours, a new write request will end up in exception "Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed".

My context.xml is

```
<Context allowLinking="true">
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/DB" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
        url="jdbc:mysql:replication://master,slave1,slave2/db"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver"
        username="user" password="pass"
        validationQuery="/* ping */ select 1" removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="300" testOnBorrow="true"
        logAbandoned="true" loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=60000
    />
</Context>
```

I am also using connection.setReadOnly & connection.setAutoCommit appropriately in mysql insert/update & select statements.

What could be possible cause of it?

Comment: maybe the admin has blocked data modifications from the database side for that resource you are trying to modify, please confirm that you can modify it from db before trying it through java code.

Comment: No, the DB user I am using has full permission. As said it works fine. The error only come in case when database write is not issued for some long time.